# Is it possible to get the revert reason during CREATE?

Tags: solidity, opcode, create, foundry, revert

I'm trying to return the revert reason of a revert that is triggered during a CREATE opcode.

I'm currently using

```
    function deployCode(bytes memory bytecode) internal returns (address payable addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))

            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
        }
    }
```

But no matter what, returndatasize() is always 0. I am stepping through the opcodes with a debugger and see that in the createcode call, there is an intermediary frame. The last steps are the following (with the first 4 bytes in memory showing my exact revert reason!)

[image: Create opcodes]

The next few codes are the following

[image: 0 returndatasize]

`returndatasize` seems to be 0. Does that mean that it's not possible to retrieve any returndata from a create call if it is unsuccessful?
Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it ain't pretty, but... for testing purposes I decided to encode the revert message in the returned bytecode during contract deployment. I made it clear by returning the STOP opcode 00 followed by the revert message and read it out as follows and then bubbled up the reason.

```
    function deployCode(bytes memory bytecode) internal returns (address payable addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))

            // can't get any custom messages out of here...

            let ext_code_size := extcodesize(addr)

            if iszero(ext_code_size) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }

            // encode reason in bytecode just so I can run my tests...
            // by checking if first byte equals 00 (STOP)

            extcodecopy(addr, 0, 0, 1)

            if iszero(mload(0)) {
                let revert_size := sub(ext_code_size, 1)
                extcodecopy(addr, 0, 1, revert_size)
                revert(0, revert_size)
            }
        }
    }
```