# How to Resolve Compiler Version Conflicts in Foundry Test Contracts?

Tags: solidity, compilation, foundry, forge, version-pragma

I'm working on a Foundry project, and I'm encountering issues with compiler versions when trying to deploy Uniswap V3 core and periphery contracts in a test contract(i.e. `UniswapTest` shown below). The test contract uses solidity 0.8, but [v3-core](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core) and [v3-periphery](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery) use solidity `0.7.6`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

import { StdCheats } from "forge-std/StdCheats.sol";

import { IUniswapV3Factory } from "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";
import { UniswapV3Factory } from "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol";
import { INonfungiblePositionManager } from "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol";
import { NonfungiblePositionManager } from "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol";

contract UniswapTest is StdCheats {

    // Uniswap V3 contracts
    IUniswapV3Factory internal uniswapV3Factory;
    INonfungiblePositionManager internal nonfungiblePositionManager;

    function setUp() public virtual {
        uniswapV3Factory = new UniswapV3Factory();
        nonfungiblePositionManager = new NonfungiblePositionManager(address(uniswapV3Factory), wethAddress);
    }

    function test_Uniswap() external {
      // ... test uniswap
    }
}
```

Attempting to `forge compile` results the following truncated compilation error:

```
Discovered incompatible solidity versions in following
: test/Uniswap.t.sol (>=0.8.0) imports:
    lib/v3-core/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol (=0.7.6)
    it continues to list all other Uniswap.t.sol imports some of which are compatible with >=0.8.0 and some which are not as is the case with the UniswapV3Factory import above
```

Additionally if `pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;` is used instead of `pragma solidity >=0.8.0;` for the `Uniswap.t.sol` file this results in the following compiler error:

> Encountered invalid solc version in test/U.t.sol: Failed to parse solidity version >=0.8.0 <0.9.0: expected comma after patch version number, found '<'

How can I deploy contracts that require a solidity version that is incompatible with the test contract's solidity version?

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/133678/86303), however it does not have a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to import contracts that are incompatible with your test contract's version and then attempting to deploy those contracts using the `new` keyword, you can instead use the [StdCheats#deployCode()](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/deployCode) function. If you want to deploy contract/s from an external library this way you'll have to first import those contract/s into one of your project files so that foundry compiles and generates the artifacts for these contracts in the output directory(i.e. the `./out` folder by default). For example you can add these imports in a `./test/mocks/Uniswap.sol` file and after compiling should observe the artifacts for these contracts in the `./out` folder:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

import { UniswapV3Factory } from "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol";
import { NonfungiblePositionManager } from "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol";
```

Now in your test file you can deploy these contracts as follows:

```
contract UniswapTest is StdCheats {

    // Uniswap V3 contracts
    IUniswapV3Factory internal uniswapV3Factory;
    INonfungiblePositionManager internal nonfungiblePositionManager;

    function setUp() public virtual {
      IUniswapV3Factory uniswapV3Factory = IUniswapV3Factory(deployCode("UniswapV3Factory.sol"));
      INonfungiblePositionManager = INonfungiblePositionManager(deployCode("NonfungiblePositionManager.sol", abi.encode(address(uniswapV3Factory), wethAddress)));
    }

    function test_Uniswap() external {
      // ... test uniswap
    }
}
```

However you may not want to deploy bytecode generated by foundry(given the configured compiler & optimizer settings) but instead deploy a specific bytecode for a contract for a reason such as the following:

In the context of Uniswap the `v3-periphery` repo has a `PoolAddress` library with a `POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH` constant which is the keccak256 hash of the `UniswapV3Pool` contract creation bytecode defined in `v3-core`, and the `PoolAddress` library is a dependency of many periphery contracts including `NonfungiblePositionManager`, so in order to have the periphery contracts function in your local foundry environment you'll want to deploy the exact `UniswapV3Factory` bytecode(which contains the `UniswapV3Pool` creation bytecode within it). The factory bytecode can be generated by running `hardhat compile` on the `Uniswap/v3-core` repo and should be visible in the `./artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json` file. You can then copy and paste the `bytecode` in to a `Precompiles` contract defined as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

import { IUniswapV3Factory } from "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";

contract Precompiles {

    bytes private constant UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_0_7_BYTE_CODE =
        hex"60a0604052348..."; // bytecode is too long to show in this message

    // taken from https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/132029/86303
    function deployCode(bytes memory bytecode) internal returns (address payable addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))

            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
        }
    }

    function deployUniswapV3Factory() public returns (IUniswapV3Factory uniswapV3Factory) {
        bytes memory creationBytecode = UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_0_7_BYTE_CODE;
        uniswapV3Factory = IUniswapV3Factory(deployCode(creationBytecode));
    }
}
```

You can then deploy the `UniswapV3Factory`(with the exact bytecode as Uniswap's V3 Factory deployments) in your test contract as follows:

```
contract UniswapTest is StdCheats {

    // Uniswap V3 contracts
    IUniswapV3Factory internal uniswapV3Factory;
    INonfungiblePositionManager internal nonfungiblePositionManager;

    Precompiles internal precompiles;

    function setUp() public virtual {
        precompiles = new Precompiles();
        uniswapV3Factory = precompiles.deployUniswapV3Factory();

        nonfungiblePositionManager = INonfungiblePositionManager(deployCode("NonfungiblePositionManager.sol", abi.encode(address(uniswapV3Factory), wethAddress, address(nonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor))));
        swapRouter = ISwapRouter(deployCode("SwapRouter.sol", abi.encode(address(uniswapV3Factory), wethAddress)));
    }

    function test_Uniswap() external {
        // test uniswap...
    }
}
```

NB:

- You may have noticed that I've ignored deploying the `NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor` contract which the `NonfungiblePositionManager` contract requires in it's constructor parameters. This is for simplicity of the example(since it's a minor dependency), but also the `NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor` contract has to be linked to the `NFTDescriptor` library and there's currently no way to [programmatically(i.e. using solidity) link a library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/142735/86303) to a contract using `StdCheats#deployCode()` in foundry.
- If you're trying to import an interface in your test contract that has an incompatible version you can simply copy paste the interface file into your project and change the pragma version directive and use this interface instead.